# Redis cross-shard connection data model

Tags: redis

I have keys for users:

```
user:1 
user:2
```

I in early modelling state and in the future i want to use cluster configuration.
I think **user:id** will be shard key.

**Now, any user can create group and invite to it other users (any user)**

Task: How to connect other sharded users, if i don't know which of user creator may be invite ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on your clustering technology and the Redis client capabilities. With a cluster-compatible client and Redis v3.0 for example, even if you're connected to the "wrong" shard - i.e. where your key isn't at - you will be redirected to the correct one.

Comment: Depends on your clustering tech - the open source cluster doesn't support MGET from multiple hash slots. OTOH, Redis Labs Enterprise Cluster does (disclaimer: I work for Redis Labs).